# render a 404 page on routing error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm trying to render the integrated 404 page in rails as an exception. I tried this but still getting the routing error page:

posts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
if current_user.username == @post.email 
@post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
else
  not_found
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
 def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

routes.rb

```
 Booklist::Application.routes.draw do
 get "pages/faq"
 get "pages/about"
 devise_for :users
 resources :posts

 root 'posts#index'
 end
```

view:

```
<% if current_user.username == post.email %>
  <font color="red">This is your post! Feel free to edit or delete it. ->  </font>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
```

`No route matches [GET] "/posts/15/destroy"`

Comment: I see the problem now `No route matches [GET] "/posts/15/destroy"`. Share the `link` code from the view which fires this action. Also, it would be handy if you share the `routes.rb`

Comment: Did you read the above comment.

Comment: yeah, I added routes.rb

Comment: Thanks! But you forgot to add the link code from the view which fires this destroy action

Comment: oh I see, there is no link code, I'm trying to prevent users from typing posts/postname/destroy in the url bar, that's what i'm doing and I don't want to see the error, I want to see a different page. everything works in the app each user can delete their own post only but view other user's posts with no problems

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos may you post your link_to destroy?? Will get idea why it is giving routing error.

Comment: If you are typing the url in browser's address bar as `/posts/15/destroy` then its incorrect. Because for `destroy` action the route generated should be `/posts/15` along with `DELETE` http request. If you look at yours it shows `GET` and url with `/posts/15/destroy`

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos Ok got you, you have destroy link in view for post owner. And you are hiding that from other users and you are trying through urls just to get execute else part. Are you passing method as delete??

Comment: ok but how do I generate a 404 if a users types in a url incorrectly anyways? if I type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/franklin that url doesn't exist and it shows me a not found page

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos See my UPDATE 2 in the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of

`render not_found`

you could use

`render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html" , status: 404`

Or

`render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html" , status: :not_found`

**UPDATE**

```
def destroy
  if current_user.username == @post.email 
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  else
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html" , status: :not_found
  end
end  ## end is missing
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to display `404` error page in `development` environment then make sure that the following is set to false in  `development.rb` file:

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

**WARNING:** This also means that you would not see any errors raised on your application(stacktrace etc in view).

Comment: tried this, same error, it looks like my else statement isn't executed, I did a `puts "test"` to see if i'd see anything in the console but nada

Comment: That means `current_user.username == @post.email ` is aalways true. Else would only be executed if above condition is false.

Comment: that's weird because I have a page listing the current user's posts only and there it shows the destroy and edit links but it doesn't show the links to posts not belonging to that user and I'm using `if current_user.username == @post.email ` as well and it works fine

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos See my UPDATE above. I found one missing `end`. Maybe it was a typo but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: yeah that's a typo, the app wouldn't run if it was a missing end thankfully :)

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos Also, how do you set @post? Do you have a before_action for `destroy`?

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos You could `puts` the values of `current_user.username and @post.email ` before the `if statement` in `destroy` action. See what it shows.

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos Finally.. Time for coffee.

Comment: @KirtiThorat +1 for warning :), but how did you understand Santos's quest? I was thinking, as he was telling it, he wants to know the reason behind 'else' part not getting executed.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Happy Gudi Padwa to you.

Comment: @AlokAnand Happy Gudi Padwa to you too. :) How did I know? OP's comment `but how do I generate a 404 if a users types in a url incorrectly anyways?`

Answer (score 1):

You need to place `not_found` in `ApplicationController`, not in `PostsController`, and then you don't need to render it, you can just call it like

```
# your code above...
else
  not_found
end
```

Comment: tried this, same error, looks like my else statement isn't being executed when in the pots url i add /destroy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a page with no page exists message, then just set the config.consider_all_requests_local = false in your Config -> environment _> development.rb file. then restart the server it will be fixed.