# Rails not rendering 404 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, actioncontroller

I have a rails app. When in production my app is throwing a routing error instead of rendering the 404.html or 500.html. Why would Rails be throwing the error instead of rendering the 404 page? (output from dev with `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`)

```
Started GET "/asdfadsfdsaf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-04 16:51:12 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/asdfadsfdsaf"):
 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your app is running, your web server will not generate the 404.

If you want to have routing errors generate a 404, please see the discussion in this article: [render a 404 page on routing error in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748697/render-a-404-page-on-routing-error-in-rails).

Answer (score 3):

Check your `config/environment/*.rb` file (correspond to your env). It should contain the following string:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Check that this value is set to `false`. In this case will be rendered `404.html` ot `500.html` files.